# Implement list views with multiple columns

Tags: android, iphone, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implement an iPhone application in jQuery mobile and Phone Gap

Using list views we can implement normal table views, nested table views.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview">
                        <li data-role="list-divider">Location</li> <!-- Section Header -------->


                        <li>Primary</a></li>
                        <li>Primary </li>
                        <li>Secondary</a></li>
                        <li>Secondary</li>

                    </ul>
```

but all these have only one column, multiple in rows.

Now I need to create a table (list view) with multiple columns.

[image]

How can I create list view with multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,I hope it will work......

```
<ul>
<li> <!--first item -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Heading1</td>
        <td>Meaning1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Heading2</td>
        <td>Meaning2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Heading3</td>
        <td>Meaning3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</li>
<li> <!-- second item -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Heading1</td>
        <td>Meaning1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Heading2</td>
        <td>Meaning2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Heading3</td>
        <td>Meaning3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</li>
</ul>
```

There is a [link](http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH05.php) wich contain good info